# playframework 1.2.x How to have my method call every time play reloads in dev mode?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I need a method to be called every time play reloads so I can use the new classes to rescan some stuff.  How can I get that without developing a full blown plugin?  ( I really just want to add something quick to my application and move on).

On a side note, is there any good tutorial on doing a play plugin?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you have any method that is run alot like NoSql.em(), and NoSql is in another jar file, it will not be in the Play.classloader and in that method, I finally do a Play.classloader.getAnnotatedResources() which gives me a List and I keep comparing the first one and when it changes, I know play reloaded.  For now, this sort of hack worked for me and the nosql layer stays up constantly with the in-memory nosql database now.

While @OnApplicationStart is NOT called "every" single time play reloads, you can use the above method to know when it does reload 100% of the time instead of 75% of the time which is about the case of using @OnApplicationStart.

Answer (score 2):

Every time your application reloads (which may be often in Dev mode), the @onApplicationStart methods are called.

Therefore, just create a bootstrap job, using @onApplicationStart and you will achieve what you need.

You can see more on this, by looking at the Play documentation for bootstrap jobs - http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.5/jobs#concepts

Comment: nope, not true.  We however found out we could call Play.classloader.getAnnotatedClasses(OurAnnotation.class); and it always returned the classes in order and we could compare classes[0] with our previous loaded class.  We knew play reloaded when the class did not equal the original one.

Comment: ps.  @ONApplicationStart IS called on "most" reloads BUT definitely not on all reloads based on our testing....we finally got it working though.